# PowerMockito.when returns null

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito, powermockito

I am not sure why `PowerMockito.when` returns `null`. This is my class under test:

```
public class A {

public Integer callMethod(){
  return someMethod();
}


private Integer someMethod(){
  //Some Code
  HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(oAuthMessage.URL);
  //Some Code
  HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
  HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost); ------1
  Integer code = httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode(); ---2
  return code;
}
}





@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({ MacmillanServiceImpl.class, PersonService.class, AuthorizeServiceImpl.class, ProvisionHelper.class, ESPHelper.class,
        DPFServiceImpl.class, TransactionLogServiceImpl.class, HttpClient.class, HttpEntity.class, InputStream.class, IOUtils.class,
        DTOUtils.class, MacmillanESPResponseDTO.class, HttpClientBuilder.class, CloseableHttpClient.class, HttpPost.class, IOUtils.class,
        HttpResponse.class, CloseableHttpResponse.class, StatusLine.class })
@PowerMockIgnore({ "javax.crypto.*", "javax.net.ssl.*" })
public class TestA {

//Spying some things here & Injecting them

@Test
public void testA() {


HttpClient httpClientMock = PowerMockito.mock(HttpClient.class);
HttpClientBuilder httpClientBuilderMock = PowerMockito.mock(HttpClientBuilder.class);
CloseableHttpClient closeableHttpClientMock = PowerMockito.mock(CloseableHttpClient.class);
HttpResponse httpResponseMock = PowerMockito.mock(HttpResponse.class);

PowerMockito.mockStatic(HttpClientBuilder.class);
given(HttpClientBuilder.create()).willReturn(httpClientBuilderMock);
when(httpClientBuilderMock.build()).thenReturn(closeableHttpClientMock);
PowerMockito.when(httpClientMock.execute(httpPost)).thenReturn(httpResponseMock); --This does not work----Line 3
//Other codes
//call the method
}
```

In line-1 I get `httpResponse` as null. I want to get a mocked `HTTPResponse` object so that I can proceed further.

I have also tried this instead of Line 3:

```
CloseableHttpResponse closeableHttpResponse = PowerMockito.mock(CloseableHttpResponse.class);
PowerMockito.when(closeableHttpClientMock.execute(httpPost)).thenReturn(closeableHttpResponse);
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems that the issue is that the `httpPost` instance that you pass when mocking is not the same as the one you pass in the execution.

What you can do to resolve this is use [Matchers.eq()](http://site.mockito.org/mockito/docs/current/org/mockito/ArgumentMatchers.html#eq(T)) when you mock, that way the `when` will be executed on every object equals to the one you pass:

```
PowerMockito.when(httpClientMock.execute(Matchers.eq(httpPost)))
  .thenReturn(httpResponseMock);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have used Matchers.any()